# Reusable code for controller in Cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I would like to create reusable code in controller in "Cakephp way". I would like to replace always one field in few controllers before render website. For example I would like to replace string in field "body". I can do this like this in show method:

```
public function show($id = null) {
  $site = $this->Sites->findById($id)->first();
  $new_value = 'test2';
  $site['body'] = str_replace('test', $new_value, $site['body']);
}
```

Is there any better way to do this in cakephp way for example in initalize method or beforeRender? I can't use behavior here.

EDIT:
I know about components, but how to use it to replace all $site['body] (in my code) for all controller methods (so I would like to do this automatic, like behavior for entity)?

Answer (score 2):

Read about [Components](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html).

> Components are packages of logic that are shared between controllers. CakePHP comes with a fantastic set of core components you can use to aid in various common tasks. You can also create your own components. If you find yourself wanting to copy and paste things between controllers, you should consider creating your own component to contain the functionality. Creating components keeps controller code clean and allows you to reuse code between different controllers.

And see [Component Callbacks](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html#component-callbacks).

Comment: I know about components, but how to use it to replace all $site['body] (in my code) for all controller methods (so I would like to do this automatic, like behavior for entity)?

Comment: Virtual property -> https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#creating-virtual-properties And no need to set anything in the controller then. Your question is totally unclear and unspecific to whatever problem you try to resolve. No idea from where your other value comes from.

Comment: I think that ater edit my question was clear. Virtual property works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use component

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html

Don't forget to load it in appController or where your need it

---

After edit :

@nexequ

Maybe if you set the beforeRender in your appController

```
public function beforeRender()
{
    debug($this->request);
}
```

In $this->request->data array you have your data to replace.

Exemple:

```
data => array(
        'Reunion' => array(
            'begin' => '2017-01-13 20:00:00',
            'end' => '2017-01-13 20:30:00'
        )
```

If you find the way to get the model ("Reunion" in my example.)

You can do a trick like

replace --> $this->request->data[$model]['body']

Comment: In beforeRender() my data is empty :( [data] => Array
        (
        )

Answer (score -1):

I found solution with burzum help, I can use virtual property in src/Model/Entity:

```
protected function _getBody() {
  $new_value = 'test2';
  $test = str_replace('test2', $new_value, $this->_properties['body']);
  return $test;
}
```

It will replace for instance 'test2' with $new_value in all controller methods.